# Writing a class decorator that applies a decorator to all methods

Tags: python, decorator

I'm trying to write a class decorator that applies a decorator to all the class' methods:

```
import inspect


def decorate_func(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print "before"
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print "after"
        return ret
    for attr in "__module__", "__name__", "__doc__":
        setattr(wrapper, attr, getattr(func, attr))
    return wrapper


def decorate_class(cls):
    for name, meth in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.ismethod):
        setattr(cls, name, decorate_func(meth))
    return cls


@decorate_class
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10
        print "__init__"

    def foo(self):
        print self.a

    @staticmethod
    def baz():
        print "baz"

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        print "bar"


obj = MyClass()
obj.foo()
obj.baz()
MyClass.baz()
obj.bar()
MyClass.bar()
```

It almost works, but `@classmethod`S need a special treatment:

```
$ python test.py
before
__init__
after
before
10
after
baz
baz
before
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 44, in <module>
    obj.bar()
  File "test.py", line 7, in wrapper
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: bar() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Is there a way to handle this problem nicely ? I inspected `@classmethod` decorated methods, but I don't see anything to differentiate them from other "types" of methods.

**Update**

Here is the complete solution for the record (using descriptors to handle `@staticmethod`S and `@classmethod`S nicely, and aix's trick to detect `@classmethod`S VS normal methods):

```
import inspect


class DecoratedMethod(object):

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, obj, cls=None):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print "before"
            ret = self.func(obj, *args, **kwargs)
            print "after"
            return ret
        for attr in "__module__", "__name__", "__doc__":
            setattr(wrapper, attr, getattr(self.func, attr))
        return wrapper


class DecoratedClassMethod(object):

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, obj, cls=None):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print "before"
            ret = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
            print "after"
            return ret
        for attr in "__module__", "__name__", "__doc__":
            setattr(wrapper, attr, getattr(self.func, attr))
        return wrapper


def decorate_class(cls):
    for name, meth in inspect.getmembers(cls):
        if inspect.ismethod(meth):
            if inspect.isclass(meth.im_self):
                # meth is a classmethod
                setattr(cls, name, DecoratedClassMethod(meth))
            else:
                # meth is a regular method
                setattr(cls, name, DecoratedMethod(meth))
        elif inspect.isfunction(meth):
            # meth is a staticmethod
            setattr(cls, name, DecoratedClassMethod(meth))
    return cls


@decorate_class
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10
        print "__init__"

    def foo(self):
        print self.a

    @staticmethod
    def baz():
        print "baz"

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        print "bar"


obj = MyClass()
obj.foo()
obj.baz()
MyClass.baz()
obj.bar()
MyClass.bar()
```

Comment: your DecoratedClassMethod and DecoratedMethod classes are exactly the same. edit to put a correct solution please.

Comment: They are different: DecoratedMethod passes the object instance while DecoratedClassMethod doesn't.

Comment: Those are so similar that it must be possible to combine them to avoid duplication. Think along the lines of `self.func(cls or obj, *args, **kwargs)`. I know that's not the same but a simple `if` statement with the right test will ultimately save you from having these two nearly identical classes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`inspect.isclass(meth.im_self)` should tell you whether `meth` is a class method:

```
def decorate_class(cls):
    for name, meth in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.ismethod):
        if inspect.isclass(meth.im_self):
          print '%s is a class method' % name
          # TODO
        ...
    return cls
```

Comment: It did the trick, thanks ! I updated my question with the complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for a comment)

I took the liberty of adding the ability to specify which methods should get decorated to your solution:

```
def class_decorator(*method_names):

    def wrapper(cls):

        for name, meth in inspect.getmembers(cls):
            if name in method_names or len(method_names) == 0:
                if inspect.ismethod(meth):
                    if inspect.isclass(meth.im_self):
                        # meth is a classmethod
                        setattr(cls, name, VerifyTokenMethod(meth))
                    else:
                        # meth is a regular method
                        setattr(cls, name, VerifyTokenMethod(meth))
                elif inspect.isfunction(meth):
                    # meth is a staticmethod
                    setattr(cls, name, VerifyTokenMethod(meth))

        return cls

    return wrapper
```

Usage:

```
@class_decorator('some_method')
class Foo(object):

    def some_method(self):
        print 'I am decorated'

    def another_method(self):
        print 'I am NOT decorated'
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers do not apply directly to python3. Based on the other great answers I have been able to come up with the following solution:

```
import inspect
import types
import networkx as nx


def override_methods(cls):
    for name, meth in inspect.getmembers(cls):
        if name in cls.methods_to_override:
            setattr(cls, name, cls.DecorateMethod(meth))
    return cls


@override_methods
class DiGraph(nx.DiGraph):

    methods_to_override = ("add_node", "remove_edge", "add_edge")

    class DecorateMethod:

        def __init__(self, func):
            self.func = func

        def __get__(self, obj, cls=None):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                ret = self.func(obj, *args, **kwargs)
                obj._dirty = True  # This is the attribute I want to update
                return ret
            return wrapper

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._dirty = True
```

Now anytime a method in the tuple `methods_to_override`  is called, the dirty flag is set. Of course, anything else can be put there too. It is not necessary to include the `DecorateMethod` class in the class whose methods need to be overriden. However, as `DecorateMehod` uses specific attributes to the class, I prefer to make a class attribute.