# Run a function every time a method in a class is called

Tags: python, class

I am trying to make a method that gets called every time a function is called, for every single function in the class. The class is a subclass of another class (in my specific case, it is a subclass of `list`).

```py
class Foo(another_class):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
        super().__init__(self.bar)

    def function_to_be_called(self):
        self.bar += 1

    def function(self):
        # do stuff

foo = Foo(0)
foo.function()
foo.inherited_function()
print(foo.bar)  # should be 2, since function and inherited_function were called
```

I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26056923/13676139) that suggests overwriting the `__getattribute__` magic method, but doing so results in infinite recursion (since the function that is called needs to be found using `__getattribute__` first), or creates very weird behaviour.

My first attempt (causes `RecursionError`):

```py
class Foo(another_class):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
        super().__init__(self.bar)

    def function_to_be_called(self):
        self.bar += 1

    def function(self):
        # do stuff

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        method = another_class.__getattribute__(self, attr)
        self.function_to_be_called()  # this required __getattribute__ to be called to find function_to_be_called, causing an infinite loop
        # even if self.function_to_be_called() is replaced with the self.bar += 1, it still causes an infinite loop as __getattribute__  is called to find bar
        return method
```

My second attempt also includes the `if callable(method)` that was in the answer, and moving the contents of `function_to_be_called` into the if statement instead of calling the function (p.s. I am changing bar to be a list as that was my original intention, and is how I found the weird behaviour):

```py
# Assume that another_class has an append method
class Foo(another_class):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
        super().__init__(self.bar)

    def function(self):
        print(self.bar)

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        method = another_class.__getattribute__(self, attr)
        if callable(method):
            self.bar.sort()  # doing something to bar, for example sorting it
        return method

foo = Foo([3, 1, 2])
print(foo)  # [3, 1, 2], although the expected result is [1, 2, 3]. it does not actually seem to be sorting it
foo.append(1)
print(foo)  # [3, 1, 2, 1], although the expected result is [1, 1, 2, 3]
foo.function()  # [1, 2, 3], the other 1 that was appended dissappears randomly (edit: I tried this again, with the actual class that I am using this in, and it seems to work for some reason), and it is sorted for some reason this time
```

Comment: you just need to use `object.__getattr__(self, "function_to_be_called")()`

Comment: But note, that won't necessarily intercept calls made to list methods from other list methods...

Comment: I'm sure this should have been asked before, but I can't really find anything better than this version... except for what you found. It should probably be updated to show proper handling for this situation, because `__getattribute__` is indeed tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the `super().__getattribute__` method (which in this case resolves to the `object.__getattribute__` method) instead to avoid recursion:

```
class Foo(list):
    def __init__(self, seq):
        super().__init__(seq)
        self.bar = 0

    def function_to_be_called(self):
        self.bar += 1

    def function(self):
        pass

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = super().__getattribute__(name)
        if callable(attr):
            super().__getattribute__('function_to_be_called')()
        return attr

foo = Foo([3, 1, 2])
foo.append(1)
foo.function()
print(foo.bar)
```

This outputs:

```
2
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHBbsMgDIbvPIVvBS2KlvYyTeq1L1FViCRmQ2JAwTns6TPItoRm8w37/399NuGT3r07vYQ4z4NVKcHFe25NIvHKINeIGqQ0zpCUPKHVDSS8/wxLpSlg5KKtRHexTbOj7VWEMzyzNVBPbiDjnSQve5SDshbHJb0O/rU@naH7693LQ4ZnFfIbkiKKpp8IV3SnPrDyFEEm21bYmRb5qjYaCqnqLfKiqoIeD7FLOfy77kHwLToiTdEtPIxp7zNU@YfrqYGugeNNlGarQkA38u77tR5CsBCNI16a@V5inr8A)

Comment: That solves the problem of the RecursionError, but the updating lists (second example) still does not seem to work, for some weird reason. (Thanks for this solution anyways)

Comment: I think the problem is that this only runs if the function run is defined in the class, and does not apply to inherited functions.

Comment: @cd-CreepArghhh It is against the [policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267058/how-to-handle-a-question-that-asks-many-things) of StackOverflow to ask multiple questions in one question (and here's the [reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371614/why-isnt-it-good-to-ask-multiple-questions-and-answers-in-one-question)). Since your second question is at its core unrelated to your first question, you should've really asked about it in a new question. This time, however, I've answered your second question with a second answer, but please keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: Never mind. I've deleted my second answer per recommendation of @KarlKnechtel . Please do ask your second question as a separate question.

Comment: Ignore the other problem, I found out that it was a problem with how I was using classes, and not related to the question.